# How pass cucumber tags in serenity 2.0.x via command line

Tags: maven, serenity-bdd, cucumber-serenity

I have a maven project which has multiple feature files

Each file has a tag, some file does not any tag

I am trying to invoke

```
mvn verify -Dit.test=MyRunner -Dtags="@mytag" -Dcucumber.options="--tags '@mytag'"
```

But the execution ignores the command line and chooses all the feature files

unfortunately I have to live serenity 2.0.x and cucumber 4.2.0

Comment: Could you try `mvn verify -Dit.test=MyRunner -Dtags="@mytag" -Dcucumber.options="--tags @mytag"`

Comment: it is not working

Answer (score 0):

I have identified my issue that I am using `verify` for `test`

And I am using `maven-failsafe-plugin` it has `configuration` and `systemPropertyVariables`, I have introduced `cucumber.options` there as shown below

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <systemPropertyVariables>
           <cucumber.options>${cucumber.options}</cucumber.options>
        </systemPropertyVariables>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

after doing this it started working